# Android log encryption using AES and RSA

Tags: android, encryption, aes, rsa

I want to mail encrypted log file from my app. Since logs can be larger I have encrypted data using AES and encrypted the key using RSA. Since the AES key is required to decrypt the log, I am sending the encrypted key and logs in the same file.

Question 1: Is this right approach ? If not what is the best approach to follow in this scenario.Below is the code for the same.

```
 public static String encrypt(String data) {
    StringBuilder encryptedData = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        // Generate AES key.
        KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        // The AES key size in number of bits.
        generator.init(256);
        SecretKey secKey = generator.generateKey();

        // Initialize AES Cipher, IV and encrypt string.
        Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
        byte[] byteCipherText = aesCipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
        String encryptedText = Base64.encodeToString(byteCipherText, Base64.DEFAULT);

        // Initialize RSA Cipher and generate public key.
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        X509EncodedKeySpec publicSpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(PUBLIC_KEY, Base64.DEFAULT));
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey puKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicSpec);
        cipher.init(Cipher.PUBLIC_KEY, puKey);

        // Encrypt key and text.
        byte[] encryptedKey = cipher.doFinal(secKey.getEncoded());
        String aesKey = Base64.encodeToString(encryptedKey, Base64.DEFAULT);
        encryptedData.append(aesKey);
        encryptedData.append(encryptedText);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return encryptedData.toString();
}
```

Comment: If you want to use RSA use RSA-KEM.

Comment: @kelalaka what is the advantage of using RSA-KEM?

Comment: It is designed for [Key encapsulation Mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_encapsulation). No need for padding.

Comment: @kelalaka: Since KEM is not supported by the Android APIs OP would have to implement it himself. The result would likely be less secure than using something already supported like RSA OAEP.

Comment: @JamesKPolk not Android API but  Bouncy Castle have it. Also, all need, after RSA keygen, a good random source and a KDF. Not so complicated like PKCS#1 v1.5 padding or OAEP. OAEP is actually should be updated with an xof instead of MFG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since the AES key is required to decrypt the log, I am sending the encrypted key and logs in the same file.
>
> Question 1: Is this right approach ? If not what is the best approach to follow in this scenario.Below is the code for the same.

The approach is correct, what I'm missing is authentication (HMAC, GCM, ...).

There are some standards how to bundle the encrypted key, content and authentication together (e.g. [CMS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3852), PKCS7, OpenPGP, ..) however if it's for your own application, you may do it your way (don't bother with standards).

> If you want to use RSA use RSA-KEM

Well, using RSA KEM you may save a little of performance skipping the padding, but I'd try if it is feasible for you. As well there's an issue when encrypting the same key material with different public keys.

I'd keep it simple - just use the properly padded RSA encryption.

I'd suggest to use OAEP padding `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding` instead of PKCS1Padding (OAEP is considered newer/safer)

Comment: For authentication purpose I was thinking to use GCM mode which will do it implicitly, right?

Comment: @AjinkyaPatil indeed, the GCM mode would do the job

Comment: Gusto, KEM `This composition of a KEM and a DEM (data encapsulation mechanism; an authenticated cipher serves as a DEM) provides the standard of IND-CCA2/NM-CCA2—ciphertext indistinguishability and nonmalleability under adaptive chosen-ciphertext attack.` See [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/74281/18298). Also, RSA-KEM easy to use.

Comment: @kelalaka the wikipedia link claims: `Note that if the same m is used to encapsulate keys for e or more recipients, and the receivers share the same exponent e, but different p, q, and n, then one can recover m via the Chinese remainder theorem. Thus, if key encapsulations for several recipients need to be computed, independent values m should be used.`  (plus additional tweaking is needed to use KEM with default crypto API in java/android)

Comment: That is usual RSA broadcast attack warning. For KEM, you generate a new key with a new random value.